# BASH Operations on a for loop object

Tags: shell-script

I'm attempting to run a bash command on a forloop object but it's trying to look for a file instead of use the forloop object.

Example:

The input file contains lines in the format of `user:password`

```
for item in $(cat myItems);do
        USER = cat $item | cut -d ":" -f1
        PASS = cat $item | cut -d ":" -f2
done
```

The result of this is that it says File $item isn't found

I also tried

```
for item in $(cat myItems);do
        USER = $(cat $item | cut -d ":" -f1)
        PASS = $(cat $item | cut -d ":" -f2)
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to achieve what you're after, and keeps to the script approach you originally intended.

```
$ cat myItems
user:pass
user2:pass2
$ for item in $(cat myItems);do
    USER=$(echo $item | cut -d ":" -f1)
    PASS=$(echo $item | cut -d ":" -f2)
    echo user $USER pass $PASS
done
user user pass pass
user user2 pass pass2
$
```

Comment: Interesting so it's more a problem with the cat command not taking variables instead of me not being able to use bash commands on variables

Comment: Indeed, you were `cat`ing a variable, rather than `echo`ing.

Comment: For `$(cat myItems)` to split on newline characters _only_, you need `IFS=$'\n'`. You also need to issue a `set -o noglob` for the `*?[` characters in there not to be taken specially. You can't use `echo` for arbitrary data, you need to quote variables so they are not split+globed.

Comment: That said, if you're dealing with simple text like 'user' and 'pass' in the fields, it's perfectly suitable.

Answer (score 5):

If you do indeed need to run some command for every line of the file, you'd write:

```
while IFS=: read -r user password rest_ignored; do
  something with "$user" and "$password"
done < myItems
```

`cat` is the command to concatenate files, the assignment syntax is `var=value` without spaces around `=`. `$(...)` can split the output of a command on newline but only if you set `$IFS` properly and disable globbing.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how your example knows that the colon is the deliminator between the username and password in the input file stream?